# how to go to another activity after an imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

after going through 5 pictures changing in an activity i want a button to appear once you reach the last image

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeUtils;

public class gt4 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView Sample1;
    Button btn_gt4_back, btn_gt4_next, btn_settingsLSN, btn_done;

    private int currentImage = 0;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.gtnframe1, R.drawable.gtnframe2, R.drawable.gtnframe3, R.drawable.gtnframe4, R.drawable.gtnframe5};

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.gt4);

        Sample1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Sample1);
        btn_gt4_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gt4_back);
        btn_gt4_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gt4_next);

        //set one click listener for image

        btn_gt4_back.setOnClickListener(btn_gt4_backChangeImageListener);
        btn_gt4_next.setOnClickListener(btn_gt4_nextChangeImageListener);

    }
    View.OnClickListener btn_gt4_nextChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //increase counter to move to next img
            currentImage++;
            currentImage = currentImage % images.length;

            Sample1.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener btn_gt4_backChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            currentImage--;
            currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;

            Sample1.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
        }
    };
}
```

currently it's continuous and after the last image it goes back to the first one, i also want the back button to dissapear after the new button for the new activity appears

idk how to do so and i already tried having a button that goes to another activity but it always appear in the screen

Comment: can you be a bit more clearer on your requirement?

Comment: i want the ImageViews to be linear and have a button appear when you reach the last one, that button then goes to another activity when clicked

Comment: That button (goes to ??? OR )TAKES YOU TO another activity? Could you clarify

Answer (score 0):

First, make a button that takes you to the next activity and put it where you want it to appear in the XML file then set visibility to gone.

Then, you could do something like this in your button's onClick (assuming btn_done is the button to show):

```
View.OnClickListener btn_gt4_nextChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //increase counter to move to next img
            currentImage++;
            currentImage = currentImage % images.length;

            Sample1.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
            
            if(currentImage == 5) {
                //set btn_done to visible and btn_gt4_back to gone
            }
        }
    };
```

If I understood your question right, this should help to get what you want

(*Sorry for not including the exact methods to do this, I don't remember them and I can't check right now, I'll edit my answer when I get the chance to check*)